# 4 wire PWM 4 stage controller

Tags: pwm, fan

hope I got an idea to build this idea I had.

I want to build a 4 stage pwm fan controller, like 25%, 50%, 75% and 100% duty cicle.

I guess it could be done doing it with cmos 4017 with a pulser switch and I could get 4 stage trigger but after that I’m lost.

Anyone could give a hand to this old guy ?

Best regards and thanks in advance

Comment: I found this video as an idea for the 4 stage trigger https://www.facebook.com/share/v/5juUHvL5j2KCFc82/?mibextid=b753im

Comment: what about 0% ?

Comment: It’s off, that’s the idea of the 5th click

Comment: I'm just pointing out that your design description does not include 0% ... please do not write a comment when you want to add information ... edit your question instead ... this site is not a forum where information is added at the end ... put everything in the question and delete the comments

Comment: get something like an `ATtiny85 module` ... a Digispark is very small